# Elasticsearch 'must not' with OR operator

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking to do below with a Elasticsearch query,

-> filter by condition X

-> get records that do not satisfy either condition A or condition B

To do this I had below initially, then realized that 'must_not' does AND between conditions A and B.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "district_id": {
                            "value": 123456
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "district_name": {
                            "query": "Mydist"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "state_id": {
                            "value": 123
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Some of the solutions suggested are quite confusing, I was wondering if there is an easy-to-understand solution. I am on version 7.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to bury two `must_not` clauses into a top-level `bool/should`. The query you're looking for is this one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "district_id": {
              "value": 123456
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "district_name": {
                    "query": "Mydist"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "state_id": {
                    "value": 123
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Val this helps a lot. I notice that 'minimum_should_match' has an important role to play here. I am not sure if this is valid, but just to help with my understanding, if I set minimum_should_match=0, is it as good as not having should clause?

Comment: If the bool query includes at least one should clause and no must or filter clauses, the default value is 1. Otherwise, the default value is 0, which means it's ok that none of the should clauses match

Comment: Just love how succinct this is, and how unlikely it is to make a mistake. :D

Comment: With a query_string query you can use the Lucene expression language and it's much more succinct: `+district_id:123456 +(-district_name:Mydist OR -state_id:123)`